# how to pass field names or column names class, employee, score to a parameter type in SSRS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssis

```sql
SELECT employees, 
       class, 
       score
FROM Company
Where @Type IN (@employees or @Score or @class)
```

I have an SSRS report requirement one parameter p1 should show column OR field names and based on our column name selection in p1 the p2 parameter should show the values

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Simply `IN (@employees, @Score, @class)`?

Comment: Does this logic even need to be in the query? You're passing the value of `@type` as a parameter too. Why do you need to check the value of one parameter has the value of at least 1 other?

Comment: I have an SSRS report requirement one parameter p1 should show column OR field names and based on our column name selection in p1 the p2 parameter should show the values

Comment: I have an SSRS report requirement one parameter p1 should show column OR field names and based on our column name selection in p1 the p2 parameter should show the values